# How do I retain the position of a div's vertical position while changing their horizontal while trying to float left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an about us page where each individual member has a div with their picture and their email and their description. However the description is in the form of an accordion which opens the desc. in the div itself. Here is an example:
[image: 1]][image]

The problem is when I open one of these descriptions the layout completely changes and it isnt all aligned the way I intend for it to be. The next members box floats to the panel instead of staying where it is vertically.
[image]

Here is the code for these sections:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: navy;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: navy;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
  
.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
    background-color: transparent;
}
  
/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
}
  
/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
/* .panel {
    width: 325px;
    padding: 0 0px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
} */

.panel {
    width: 433px;
    padding: 0 0px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.maile {
    content: '\2709';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: navy;
    float: right;
}

.IconColor {
    color: navy;
    float: left;
}

.dividerr{
    border-right: solid white;
}



/* Three columns side by side */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
  
  /* Display the columns below each other instead of side by side on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    }
}
  
  /* Add some shadows to create a card effect */
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
  
  /* Some left and right padding inside the container */
.container {
    padding: 0 16px;
}
  
  /* Clear floats */
.container::after, .row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
  
.title {
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    </head>

    <body>
      <!-- The Team -->
      <div style="padding: 12px 30px;">
        <h1 style="padding-bottom: 32px;">Our Team</h1>

        <!-- First Row -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="John Tetty" style="width:100%">
              <div class="container">
                <h2>John Tetty</h2>
                <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
                <a href="mailto:" title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
                <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
                <div class="panel">
                  <p class="desc">
                    <h6>Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects
                      of investments. Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.</h6>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="John" style="width:100%">
              <div class="container">
                <h2>John Tetty</h2>
                <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
                <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
                <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
                <div class="panel">
                  <p class="desc">
                    <h6>Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects
                      of investments. Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.</h6>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="john" style="width:100%">
              <div class="container">
                <h2>John Tetty</h2>
                <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
                <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
                <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
                <div class="panel">
                  <p class="desc">
                    <h6>Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects
                      of investments. Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.</h6>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Second Row -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="john" style="width:100%">
                <div class="container">
                  <h2>John Tetty</h2>
                  <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
                  <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
                  <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
                  <div class="panel">
                    <p class="desc">
                      <h6>Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects
                        of investments. Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.</h6>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="john" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="container">
                    <h2>John Tetty</h2>
                    <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
                    <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
                    <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
                    <div class="panel">
                      <p class="desc">
                        <h6>Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects
                          of investments. Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.</h6>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="john" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="container">
                    <h2>John Tetty</h2>
                    <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
                    <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
                    <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
                    <div class="panel">
                      <p class="desc">
                        <h6>Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects
                          of investments. Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.</h6>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You cannot have an `h6` inside a `p`. Also no other headline, div or any other block element.

Comment: Why not make your *opening* element **position: absolute** so you take it out of the flow and then position it using top/left so it is*relative* to its parent container that also contains the image element.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a CSS grid and set your `.panel` elements to `position: absolute;`.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    panel.classList.toggle('open');
  });
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.card {
  position: relative;
}


/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

.accordion {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: navy;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: navy;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

.panel {
  background-color: white;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.panel.open {
  max-height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99;
}

.maile {
  content: '\2709';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: navy;
  float: right;
}

.IconColor {
  color: navy;
  float: left;
}

.dividerr {
  border-right: solid white;
}


/* Three columns side by side */


/* Display the columns below each other instead of side by side on small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Add some shadows to create a card effect */

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Some left and right padding inside the container */

.container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}


/* Clear floats */

.container::after,
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.title {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- First Row -->
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="John Tetty" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:" title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="John" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="john" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="John Tetty" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:" title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="John" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="john" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="John Tetty" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:" title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="John" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="imagesx/manjohn.jpg" alt="john" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>John Tetty</h2>
      <p class="title">President &amp; Founder</p>
      <a href="mailto:  " title="  "><i class="fa fa-envelope IconColor"></i></a>
      <button class="accordion" title="About Me"></button>
      <div class="panel">
        <p class="desc">
          Hi! My name is John, a student. I started investing using Robinhood in 2019. I have a YouTube channel called Mrwhosetheboss, which I started in 2021. Mrwhosetheboss functions as a platform to share information about the different aspects of investments.
          Now working with the London Youth board, I have started the UK to improve financial stability through financial literacy. I enjoy playing basketball and spending time with family and friends.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```